# Equal vertically spaced columns layout

Tags: android, xml, layout

[image]

I want to make this layout on my main screen of my application.
I have stripes for each image block shown above.
Please guide my which layout (RelativeLayout, LinearLayout...etc) should I use to achieve this.
I am new to android development. I have experimented few layout but not having success. I also used FrameLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:stretchColumns="1">

        <TableRow>
            <FrameLayout 
                android:id="@+id/inboxLargeButton"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:src="@drawable/inbox_normal" 
                    android:id="@+id/buttonWeddingDayCheatSheet"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
                </ImageView>
                <TextView  
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
                    android:text="2631"  
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"  
                    android:gravity="center"  
                    android:textColor="#fff"  
                    android:textSize="50dp" />
            </FrameLayout>

            <FrameLayout 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1">
                <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:src="@drawable/outbox_normal" 
                    android:id="@+id/buttonShareFavoriteRecipe"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
                </ImageView>
                <TextView  
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
                    android:text="0296"  
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"  
                    android:gravity="center"  
                    android:textColor="#fff"  
                    android:textSize="50dp" />
                </FrameLayout>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>
            <FrameLayout 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:src="@drawable/header_left_normal" 
                    android:id="@+id/buttonWeddingDayCheatSheet"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
                </ImageView>
                <TextView  
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
                    android:text="Most sent"  
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"  
                    android:gravity="center"  
                    android:textColor="#fff"  
                    android:textSize="15dp" />
            </FrameLayout>

            <FrameLayout 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1">
                <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:src="@drawable/header_right_normal" 
                    android:id="@+id/buttonShareFavoriteRecipe"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
                </ImageView>
                </FrameLayout>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
            <FrameLayout 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:src="@drawable/body_left_normal" 
                    android:id="@+id/buttonWeddingDayCheatSheet"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
                </ImageView>
            </FrameLayout>

            <FrameLayout 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1">
                <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:src="@drawable/body_right_normal" 
                    android:id="@+id/buttonShareFavoriteRecipe"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
                </ImageView>
                </FrameLayout>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
```

As I want to make the each block clickable too.

Comment: your issue is not clearly stated, but it is probably related to `android:stretchColumns="1"`

Comment: Its already there, android:stretchColumns="1"

Comment: yes, that's what i am saying. you should not be stretching a column in particular, if you want a uniform distribution

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="1" >

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/inboxLargeButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/buttonWeddingDayCheatSheet"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
            </ImageView>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="2631"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="50dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/buttonShareFavoriteRecipe"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
            </ImageView>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="0296"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="50dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/buttonWeddingDayCheatSheet"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
            </ImageView>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Most sent"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="15dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/buttonShareFavoriteRecipe"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
            </ImageView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/buttonWeddingDayCheatSheet"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
            </ImageView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/buttonShareFavoriteRecipe"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
            </ImageView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: any comment/explanation as to why you would think your solution would work? (that would be nice for those who don't want to go through all the code)